# Estimating a restricted (sparse) VAR in R

Tags: r, vector-autoregression

Assume that I want to estimate a VAR or SVAR model for some monthly economical time series without a long history (i.e. in the range of 2000-2016, which consists of only ~180 data per variable). However, because of deep underlying covariances between the data a low order VAR(p) is not suitable, I want to estimate i.e. VAR(24) model. Assuming I'm doing this only for 2-3 variables, I'm still estimating too many (insignificant) parameters for the data I've got.

My question is: what R packages allows restricting some VAR coefficients to 0 and estimating only the remaining ones using R?

So far I've found `vars` and `MTS` packages, both of which allows to specify a (i.e.) VAR(24) model and by using `restrict()` or `refVAR()` accordingly, to iteratively reestimate the models by restricting some coefficients to 0 by their t-statistics (by setting, for example, `thres = 1.96` in the `refVAR`). The problem I've noticed here is that all of the (re)estimations are done by OLS (correct me if I'm wrong here), though, as far as I remember from  Lütkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis", a restricted VAR should be estimated by FGLS instead of OLS.

However, I haven't yet found any package in R that allows estimating a VAR in FGLS (and which allows a restriction by some criteria). Is there any which I've missed?

Additionally, I've found a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0520.pdf) that discusses sparse VAR's and LASSO-VAR's, but, again, I was unable to find any R packages for these or similar methods.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are only asking for R packages, that is off topic here. If you have a statistical question about VAR models in this situation, please edit to clarify.

Comment: @gung Thanks. Yes, so far I'm interested in R packages only. Sorry, if I posted this at the wrong board. Is there a way to transfer this question to stack overflow boards, or should I just repost it there and delete this one?

Comment: This will be off topic on [SO] as well. Your best bet may be to ask on the r-help listserv. Note that there is a [finance](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance) SIG list (although I've never posted there).

Comment: You could try manually excluding most of the lags. E.g. if you have monthly data, try VAR($p$) + lag number 12 plus (plus perhaps lag number 24) where $p$ is small, e.g. 2 or 3. Regarding GLS versus OLS, in small samples GLS need not always be better than OLS due to estimation variance; I think Lütkepohl mentions that at some point.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks, that sounds reasonable. Not sure if I remember correctly, but if we'd construct a structural VAR with triangular structural matrix, we'd have a recursive structure of equations for which OLS is plausible. The question then: if we restrict a VAR with ``restrict()`` in ``vars`` package, and then calculate a SVAR from it, do the parameters get reestimated efficiently in recursive, or are they only multiplied inside the ``SVAR`` function by the $A_0$ structural matrix, but the initial estimates from the restricted VAR are (possibly) inefficient because of restricted VAR OLS?

Comment: I don't know. Try consulting the package manual and/or vignette, and/or the help files for the particular functions you would be using.

Comment: See R packages "BigVAR", "nets" and code of Luca Barbaglia and coauthors [here](https://feb.kuleuven.be/Luca.Barbaglia/research) for fitting VAR with LASSO.